# Generating a graphical non-fungible token

Tags: blockchain

How can I generate a graphical non-fungible token, for ex: a crypto-kitty.
Let's say I have some svg files with some border designs, text designs, colors, etc. Is there a way to automatically generate a badge(NFT) that randomly picks a border, text, and color and provides a complete image of it??
Because if someone sits to generate these images manually, then it would take a lot of time in generating all the various combinations.
Thanks in advance!